# Error: flutter.sdk not set in local.properties. Expression: (flutterSdkPath != null). Values: flutterSdkPath = null

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, sdk

Settings file `C:\My Projects\...\android\settings.gradle line: 10`

A problem occurred evaluating settings `android`.

> flutter.sdk not set in local.properties. Expression: (flutterSdkPath != null). Values: flutterSdkPath = null

- Try:
  Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output. Run with `--scan` to get full insights.

I imported a project `build.gradle` , getting error like `flutter.sdk` not set in `local.properties`, I tried alot to solve but filed

### local.properties

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```